# How to capture infrared stream from webcam using ffmpeg?

Tags: webcam, ffmpeg

I'm able to capture from my webcam using ffmpeg, but it's real color.  But my webcam is advertised as having IR capability.  How do I access this?

When I run `ffmpeg -f v4l2 -list_formats all -i /dev/video0` I get this output:

```
Compressed:       mjpeg :          Motion-JPEG : 1280x720 640x360 640x480 848x480 960x540
Raw       :     yuyv422 :           YUYV 4:2:2 : 160x120 320x180 320x240 424x240 640x360 640x480
```

The camera specs are given as video: 1280x720 at 30 fps, IR Video: 340x340 at 60 fps

Also, here is the output of `v4l2-ctl --list-devices`:

```
Integrated_Webcam_HD: Integrate (usb-0000:00:14.0-11):
    /dev/video0
    /dev/video1
```

I thought maybe the Raw stream would contain the Infrared video stream, but when I run this:

```
ffplay -input_format yuyv422 -video_size 320x240 -i /dev/video0
```

The output looks identical to the 1280x720 output except smaller.

I also ran `ffmpeg -f v4l2 -list_formats all -i /dev/video1` and got this output:

```
Raw       : Unsupported : 00000032-0002-0010-8000-00aa003 : 640x360
```

But I don't seem to be able to play anything from this device, I get:

```
Cannot find a proper format for codec 'none' (id 0), pixel format 'none' (id -1)
Assertion *codec_id != AV_CODEC_ID_NONE failed at src/libavdevice/v4l2.c:811
```

How do I capture infrared video from the webcam?

Comment: What is the model of the web camera ?

Comment: @EchoMike444 Can ffmpeg tell me that?  It's built into my laptop

Comment: What does `v4l2-ctl --list-devices` show?

Comment: @llogan I have updated my question to include the output of this command.

Comment: Did you finally achieve this goal?